# Hive shell is not starting up

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hive

```
lalitha@lalitha-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/apache-hive-0.13.0-bin$ hive
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/lalith/Downloads/apache-hive-0.13.0-bin/lib/hive-common-0.13.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
```

I am running a single node hadoop cluster on ubuntu.
I have seen many answers upon this question, I tried all of them, still the error persists.

hive-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/home/lalitha/Downloads/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/metastore_db;create=true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
<value>/hive/warehouse</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
<value/>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
<value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass</name>
<value>org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Could anyone please help me.

EDIT: 
Following is the output after running:
 hive -hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console

```
lalitha@lalitha-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/apache-hive-0.13.0-bin$ hive -hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console
18/06/30 13:34:48 [main]: DEBUG common.LogUtils: Using hive-site.xml found on CLASSPATH at /home/lalitha/Downloads/apache-hive-0.13.0-bin/conf/hive-site.xml

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/lalitha/Downloads/apache-hive-0.13.0-bin/lib/hive-common-0.13.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
18/06/30 13:34:48 [main]: INFO SessionState: 
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/lalitha/Downloads/apache-hive-0.13.0-bin/lib/hive-common-0.13.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
18/06/30 13:34:48 [main]: DEBUG parse.VariableSubstitution: Substitution is on: hive
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.storeManagerType value null from  jpox.properties with rdbms
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding javax.jdo.option.NonTransactionalRead value null from  jpox.properties with true
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.autoStartMechanismMode value null from  jpox.properties with checked
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.transactionIsolation value null from  jpox.properties with read-committed
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.fixedDatastore value null from  jpox.properties with false
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.validateColumns value null from  jpox.properties with false
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL value null from  jpox.properties with jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/home/lalitha/Downloads/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/metastore_db;create=true
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.validateConstraints value null from  jpox.properties with false
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.identifierFactory value null from  jpox.properties with datanucleus1
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass value null from  jpox.properties with org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.cache.level2 value null from  jpox.properties with false
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.rdbms.useLegacyNativeValueStrategy value null from  jpox.properties with true
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown value null from  jpox.properties with false
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding javax.jdo.option.DetachAllOnCommit value null from  jpox.properties with true
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName value null from  jpox.properties with org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding javax.jdo.option.Multithreaded value null from  jpox.properties with true
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.plugin.pluginRegistryBundleCheck value null from  jpox.properties with LOG
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.validateTables value null from  jpox.properties with fals
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.autoCreateSchema value null from  jpox.properties with true
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.cache.level2.type value null from  jpox.properties with none
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding datanucleus.connectionPoolingType value null from  jpox.properties with BONECP
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: Overriding javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName value null from  jpox.properties with APP
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.rdbms.useLegacyNativeValueStrategy = true
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown = false
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.autoStartMechanismMode = checked
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: javax.jdo.option.Multithreaded = true
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.identifierFactory = datanucleus1
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.transactionIsolation = read-committed
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.validateTables = false
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/home/lalitha/Downloads/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/metastore_db;create=true
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: javax.jdo.option.DetachAllOnCommit = true
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: javax.jdo.option.NonTransactionalRead = true
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.fixedDatastore = false
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.validateConstraints = false
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName = org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName = APP
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.validateColumns = false
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.cache.level2 = false
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.plugin.pluginRegistryBundleCheck = LOG
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.cache.level2.type = none
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass = org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.autoCreateSchema = true
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.storeManagerType = rdbms
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: DEBUG metastore.ObjectStore: datanucleus.connectionPoolingType = BONECP
18/06/30 13:34:49 [main]: INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
18/06/30 13:34:51 [main]: DEBUG bonecp.BoneCPDataSource: JDBC URL = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/home/lalitha/Downloads/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/metastore_db;create=true, Username = APP, partitions = 1, max (per partition) = 10, min (per partition) = 0, idle max age = 60 min, idle test period = 240 min, strategy = DEFAULT
18/06/30 13:34:52 [main]: ERROR Datastore.Schema: Failed initialising database.
Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/home/lalitha/Downloads/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/metastore_db;create=true, username = APP.
Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/home/lalitha/Downloads/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/metastore_db' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@154617c, see the next exception for details.
at     org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver20.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:361)
at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:501)
at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:298)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1187)
at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:356)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:775)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:333)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:309)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:338)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:247)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:222)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:476)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:524)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:398)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.<init>(HiveMetaStore.java:357)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:59)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:4948)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:171)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2444)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2456)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:338)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/home/lalitha/Downloads/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/metastore_db' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@154617c, see the next exception for details.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 72 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /home/lalitha/Downloads/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/metastore_db.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
... 69 more
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /home/lalitha/Downloads/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/metastore_db.
```

Still a lot more errors are there.
I am a new bie to hadoop and could not find what was the mistake and what was happening here.

Comment: Try deleting the derby database path mentioned in that output first. Also, it's recommended you use Mysql or Postgres anyway, not Derby. Take a minute to set those up

Answer (score 0):

Could you try running the following command and paste the output here?

```
hive -hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console
```

Edit - 
The output says
    "Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database 
    /home/lalitha/Downloads/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/metastore_db."
This seems to be a problem. Do a "ps -ef | grep hive" and kill all the processes and retry executing the command.

Comment: I added the output in the EDIT section above.

Comment: The output says "Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /home/lalitha/Downloads/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/metastore_db.". This seems to be a problem. Do as "ps -ef | grep hive" and kill all the processes and retry executing the command.